# Generalising Rasters using .ovr pyramid data?

Tags: python, gdal, generalization, image-pyramids

I have to produce some lower spatial resolution rasters from a large number of very big geotiffs (c.800GB).

It occured to me that since I've produced the pyramid overviews using GDAL already  I could do this by using the data in the *.ovr files without incurring much additional processing.

Does anyone know of an elegant way of doing this using GDAL or Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GDAL > 2.0 you can use the open option `OVERVIEW_LEVEL`.

> [-oo NAME=VALUE](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html):
>       (starting with GDAL 2.0) Dataset open option (format specific)

```
gdal_translate -oo OVERVIEW_LEVEL=2 fullres.tif reducedres.tif

0=original (no overview)
1=first overview level
2=second overview level
...
```